# Determining if GPU switching works?

Tags: linux, graphics, fglrx, ati, intel-gma

I have a 8,3 MacBook Pro with an onboard Radeon 6700M GPU alongside the integrated Intel Sandy Bridge GPU. I recently upgraded to FGLRX 8.930/12.1, and Catalyst Control Center seemed to look the same, there weren't any different options as opposed to 8.920/11.12. However, [here](http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com/2012/01/improved-support-for-amd-hybrid.html) it mentions that someone tested things out and was able to determine that with FGLRX on the same card as me, they were able to determine that GPU switching was, in fact, working.

Unfortunately, the blog doesn't allow comments, so I can't ask this question there. Is there a way for me to determine if GPU switching is working or not between ATI and Intel cards?

How can I know if it's working or not? Again, there doesn't seem to be anything in CCC that tells me whether it's enabled or not. There's "PowerPlay," but that seems to be more of a setting for battery-saving in general and doesn't make any mention of GPU switching.

How can I test if GPU-switching/hybrid graphics is enabled and working on my Ubuntu 11.10 machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, FGLRX graphics switching will not work on mbp 8,x model.  The only way to use fglrx for your model is through BIOS emulation mode, and because of that it will not work.

You can however get graphics switching to work on your model by setting up EFI boot.  Doing so is not easy and requires a series of grub2/kernel patches.  Instead of using the FGLRX, you will be using the opensource radeon drivers.  Following the directions at this link http://dentifrice.poivron.org/laptops/macbookpro8,2/ should help.  I must warn you that the open source radeon drivers are a bit lacking in the 3d department (performance wise), but the open source Intel drivers are very good.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a device file with the fglrx driver but you can run glxinfo and fglrxinfo on both video cards and it should show a massive improvement over the onboard video card. With switcheroo there is a device file that can switch the wanted power state and the wanted video card. My onboard video card copy up to 50 fps to the video buffer when my discrete video card copy up to 1500 fps with fglrxinfo with fglrx driver and glxinfo with the open source driver.